# MSBuild on TFS failed - WebDeploy Package

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild, iis-express, webdeploy

I'm currently working on a build for a project, but I'm facing difficulties with the TFS Build.
I just want to create a zip package, using a TFS Build, with parameters from IIS Express.

CSPROJ configuration:
[image: Web]

[image: Package/Publish Web]

IIS Express is present on my machine and on the build server (I can access to the *.svc files in the project).
And all is on source control.

When I use the "Build Deployment Package" on my machine, I've got the zip.
When I use the "Build Deployment Package" on the build server, I've got the zip.
When I use the MSBuild's command line on both, I've got the zip.

The command line in question :

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" "C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj" /p:Platform=AnyCPU;Configuration=Release /p:DeployTarget=Package /p:DeployOnBuild=true;DefaultPackageFileName=ZipName.zip
```

But when I put the same command line in a build, it fails:

```
"C:\Builds\2\[...]\Project.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(PackageUsingManifest target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3009,5): error : Web deployment task failed.(Object of type 'manifest' and path 'C:\Builds\2\Project Release\Binaries\_PublishedWebsites\Project_Package\Project.SourceManifest.xml' cannot be created.) [C:\Builds\2\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3009,5): error :  [C:\Builds\2\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3009,5): error : Object of type 'manifest' and path 'C:\Builds\2\Project Release\Binaries\_PublishedWebsites\Project_Package\Project.SourceManifest.xml' cannot be created. [C:\Builds\2\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3009,5): error : One or more entries in the manifest 'sitemanifest' are not valid. [C:\Builds\2\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3009,5): error : Site '' does not exist. [C:\Builds\2\[...]\Project.csproj]
```

Additional Infos, line 3009 refer to:

```
<VSMSDeploy Condition="!$(UseMsdeployExe)"
   MSDeployVersionsToTry="$(_MSDeployVersionsToTry)"
   Source="@(MsDeploySourceProviderSetting)"
   Destination="@(MsDeployDestinationProviderSetting)"
   DeploymentTraceLevel="$(PackageTraceLevel)"
   DisableLink="$(PackageDisableLinks)"
   EnableLink="$(PackageEnableLinks)"
   DeclareParameterItems="@(_Package_MsDeployDeclareParameters)"
   OptimisticParameterDefaultValue="$(EnableOptimisticParameterDefaultValue)"
   ImportDeclareParametersItems="$(_VsPackageParametersFile)"
   ReplaceRuleItems="@(MsDeployReplaceRules)"
   RetryAttempts="$(RetryAttemptsForDeployment)">
```

I know I'm missing something, but I don't see what... so, if you have suggestions...it will be very welcome! :)

The tfs build did not run with the same account than me when I'm logged on the build server.
Is IIS Express is well launch with a tfs build ?
When I look in `C:\Users\svcTfsBuild\Documents`, there is no IISExpress directory, like with my user (svcTfsBuild is the service account for TFS Build).

**The main goal:**

- Obtain a zip package with a tfs build with those parameters (parameters.xml within the zip package).
- **OR**
- Have a zip package where we can specify Application Pool and Physical Path when importing.

Like this:

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="IIS Web Application Name" defaultValue="Default Web Site/Project" tags="IisApp">
    <parameterEntry kind="ProviderPath" scope="AppHostConfig" match="^ProjectTest/Project$" />
    <parameterEntry kind="ProviderPath" scope="contentPath" match="^C:\\WORKSPACES\\[...]\\obj\\Release\\Package\\PackageTmp$" />
    <parameterEntry kind="ProviderPath" scope="setAcl" match="^C:\\WORKSPACES\\[...]\\obj\\Release\\Package\\PackageTmp$" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="IIS Web Application Pool Name" defaultValue="ASP.NET v4.0">
    <parameterEntry kind="DeploymentObjectAttribute" scope="application" match="application[@applicationPool='Clr4IntegratedAppPool']/@applicationPool" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="IisVirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath" defaultValue="D:\CompanyName\Project" tags="PhysicalPath">
    <parameterEntry kind="DestinationVirtualDirectory" scope=".*" match="^C:\\WORKSPACES\\[...]$" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

Note : we can's specify the configuration in a parameters.xml directly on the csproj because the workspace are not the same on our machines, on the tfs build server...

I hope this is clear

**EDIT: suggestion from drk**

Like you said, I run the command line from the service account, and got this, in particular:

```
GenerateMsdeployManifestFiles:
  Generate source manifest file for Web Deploy package/publish ...
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018: The "IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: Object of type 'package' and path 'C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\obj\Release\Package\Project.zip' cannot be created. ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: The Zip package 'C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\obj\Release\Package\Project.zip' could not be loaded. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\obj\Release\Package\Project.zip' is denied. [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Win32Native.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FileStreamEx.CreateInstance(String path, FileMode fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess, FileShare fileShare) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipFile.Load() [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipPackageProvider..ctor(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, String path) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipPackageProvider.GetAttributes(DeploymentAddAttributeContext addContext) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.EnsureValidAttributes() [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObjectPrivate(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentObject sourceObject) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(String provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentWellKnownProvider provider, String path) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.DynamicAssembly.CallStaticMethod(String typeName, String methodName, Object[] arguments) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded.Execute() [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult) [C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj]
Done Building Project "C:\WORKSPACES\[...]\Project.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

I've checked the service account (SvcTfsBuild in my case).
He has full control over the workspace (so the source code).
And my account and the SvcTfsBuild account are on the same groups (local administrator).

But the TFS BUILD log (verbose mode) did not show any permission problem...

**EDIT 2013/03/25**

I've uncheck the checkbox "Use IIS Express" in the Web tab.
The build generate the good zip package.
***So, I asume there is a problem only with IIS Express.***

In the build, I've had an "InvokeProcess" on the sequence "Run On Agent", just after "CreateLabel".
It launch ISS Express with those arguments :

```
/site:Project-Site
```

In the log file, I've got a Result to 0 (so, I assume ISS Express is well launch, if not, it is supposed to throw an exception).
But, if the command line is not well formed or wrong (ie: with /site and /path wich cannot be combined), the result is also 0.
And if I launch ISS Express that way, the build is stopped (iisexpress wait a manual action to stop or just listen).

**EDIT 2 2013/03/25**

To launch IIS Express in the same time than the build, I've made this :
[image: TFBUILD]

On the Parallel, I've got a variable named "BuildFinished" wich is set to True in the Finally of the build process (on left).

But, I've again the same error (Site '' does not exist).

I've also find a difference between the two Project.SourceManifest.xml when build through "Build Deployment Package" (in VS2010) and through the TFBUILD.

Build Deployment Package :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sitemanifest>
  <appHostConfig path="Project-Site/Project" />
  <contentPath path="C:\WORKSPACES\Project\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp" />
  <setAcl path="C:\WORKSPACES\Project\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp" setAclResourceType="Directory" />
  <setAcl path="C:\WORKSPACES\Project\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp" setAclUser="anonymousAuthenticationUser" setAclResourceType="Directory" />
</sitemanifest>
```

TFBUILD :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sitemanifest>
  <appHostConfig path="/Project" />
  <contentPath path="C:\Builds\1\Project\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp" />
  <setAcl path="C:\Builds\1\Project\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp" setAclResourceType="Directory" />
  <setAcl path="C:\Builds\1\Project\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp" setAclUser="anonymousAuthenticationUser" setAclResourceType="Directory" />
</sitemanifest>
```

The path value is not the same.

Comment: I would suggest to run the command under build service account to see the full output, sounds like a permision issue. What account the tfs build is running under ?

Comment: You're right for the permision issue with the service account. I've edit the question with the relevant output.

Comment: Try to create that file manualy under svc account, check permisions or ownership if it exists and on folder, could be UAC related as well.

Comment: Well, I've done what you've suggest. This is better. Now, I've got the same errors than in the build ^^ (Site '' does not exist.)

Comment: I've launch manually the IIS Express and then build from the command line. It works. But, even if the IIS Express is launch for the serviçe account, the build failed with the same message.
So, I'm done for today, next episode on monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of trys, I think the problem is between IIS Express and MSDeploy wich can't work together (this is the one saying "`Site '' does not exist.`").

So, instead of thrying to make it work, we change our mind to use a configuration wich works: modifying the csproj during the build processs in order to use IIS.

Step 1:  IIS on the build server

1. Create an application pool: the name and the Framework version are the two things that matters. Nothing more.
2. Create the application: name and application pool are important. You can use C:\temp as physical path.

Step 2: Build's definition
You have two choices: create a custom build activity (better one) or do it inside the xaml (ugly one).
The goal, is to have the followings steps:

1. On the "Run On Agent" sequence, just after the "If Create Label"
2. Remove the readonly attribute on the targeted csproj (the one on the workspace created by TFS)
3. Read the csproj's content
4. Replace the following XML tags

`<UseIISExpress>True</UseIISExpress>` by `<UseIISExpress>False</UseIISExpress>`
`<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>` by `<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>`
`<IncludeIisSettings>False</IncludeIisSettings>` by `<IncludeIisSettings>true</IncludeIisSettings>`
`<IISUrl>{IIS Express URL}</IISUrl>` by `<IISUrl>{IIS URL}</IISUrl>`
/!\ Beware: the booleans can be True or true!
/!\ Beware2: if using Cassini, the IISUrl's tag may have a word wrap, like:

```
`<IISUrl>  
</IISUrl>`
```

This happened only with one of the 4 dev's machine.

{IIS Express URL}: is like `http://localhost:8080/` or `http://localhost:8080/Application` with IIS Express or empty with Cassini.
{IIS URL}: is like `http://localhost/Application`.

And finally, overwrite the csproj (remember, the one in the TFS's workspace, not the on on source control) with the modify content.

{IIS Express URL} and {IIS URL} can be arguments from the build, but only if the build take the csproj one by one (1 build = 1 zip package, so 1 csproj have to be modified).

With that solution (I think there is a better one that I don't know), we use a configuration that we know it works.

When the zip package will be import in IIS, the application pool and the physical path can be change.
And this is our goal.

Hope this helps.